# MySQL does not store properly some UTF8 chars

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using the **mysql** dbms to store pages from Wikipedia. I've set the character-set encoding to `utf-8` (wikipedia encoding) in my.cnf file with the directive:

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8
```

And created my database with the `'chararacter set utf8'` property definition.

I've also changed the charset-encoding for mysqld client by:

- inserting the `'charSet=utf8'` property when initializing my jdbc driver.
- doing a query to `'set names utf8'`

However I've noticed that mysql server replaces some characters with others.

For example it replaces `á` with `a`.

**UPDATE**

I've run the command `show variables like '%char%'` ensuring that both `character_set_client` and `character_set_set` are `utf8`.

How can I store the correct chars in my db? Thanks!

Comment: [1]Which driver are you using? [2]Are you using `new String([String Object].getBytes(), "UTF-8")` before setting the parameter to store in the database?

Comment: [1]I'm using MySQL Connector/J. [2] I've tried `new String([String Object].getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you insert a UTF-8 text from the MySQL Workbench or a similar tool? If so, then as Eran pointed out, it might be related to your connection URL settings.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to store utf8 strings with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: When you ran the `show variables` command, what was the value of `character_set_server`? Did you try my suggestion below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify the encoding in the DB URL :

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/DBNAME?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Here's some more information regarding my answer :

The following is taken from the MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html) :

> All strings sent from the JDBC driver to the server are converted
>   automatically from native Java Unicode form to the client character
>   encoding, including all queries sent using Statement.execute(),
>   Statement.executeUpdate(), Statement.executeQuery() as well as all
>   PreparedStatement and CallableStatement parameters with the exclusion
>   of parameters set using setBytes(), setBinaryStream(),
>   setAsciiStream(), setUnicodeStream() and setBlob().
>
> **Setting the Character Encoding**
>   The character encoding between client
>   and server is automatically detected upon connection. You specify the
>   encoding on the server using the character_set_server for server
>   versions 4.1.0 and newer. The driver automatically uses the encoding
>   specified by the server.  To override the automatically detected
>   encoding on the client side, use the characterEncoding property in the
>   URL used to connect to the server.  To allow multiple character sets
>   to be sent from the client, use the UTF-8 encoding, either by
>   configuring utf8 as the default server character set, or by
>   configuring the JDBC driver to use UTF-8 through the characterEncoding
>   property.

I encountered a similar problem a few months ago. I checked the default value of character_set_server on my MySQL (using the “mysqld --verbose –help” command).
It was latin1.