# Query works on phpMyAdmin, but not in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I'm using MySQL and JDBC to the database for a site in JSP.

I generate an SQL query for a search command, the query works when I run it manually on phpMyAdmin and it return 1 row match.

But after executing my query the *ResultSet* is empty (I can't get the values of the table).

This is the code that executes the query:

```
public static Product findLikeProd(String ProductName)
{
    Product Product = null;
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = Database.executeSelect1("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodName LIKE '%"+ProductName+"%' AND exist=1");
        if (rs.next())
        {
            Product = new Product(rs.getInt("PKid"), rs.getString("prodName"), rs.getString("description"), rs.getDouble("price"), rs.getInt("deliveryTime"), rs.getString("imgUrl"));
        }
        //Database.closeCon();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Product;
}
```

A query for example:

> SELECT * FROM Products WHERE prodName LIKE '%מהיר%' AND exist=1

The code:

```
public synchronized static ResultSet executeSelect1(String sqlCmd) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setServerName("localhost");
        ds.setDatabaseName("tarazJsp"); 
        con=ds.getConnection("root","");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sqlCmd); //The problem is here. rs is received(!=null) but I can't get his parameters.(empty)

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rs;
}
```

When I try to get the string from *rs*, it throws an SQLException.

How should I fix it?

Comment: What is duplicate of SQL query?

Comment: You have posted two (almost) identical/duplicate questions. Delete on of them not to pollute SO

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738732/mysql-does-not-store-properly-some-utf8-chars/14738790#14738790)

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the MySQL connection encoding, so the default encoding will be used. The default encoding is likely `latin1`, which doesn't include Hebrew characters. This means that the SQL MySQL will actually execute will be more like `... WHERE prodName LIKE '%????%' ...` and that's not returning any results.

A possible fix is setting an encoding that does support Hebrew, like `utf8`:

```
    ds.setServerName("localhost");
    ds.setEncoding("utf8");
```

Comment: I thought about it but in phpmyadmin i created the columns as utf-8, and when i add this line ds.setEncoding("utf8"); , The problem stay as it is, The sql query is ... WHERE prodName LIKE '%מהיר%' ... so the problem i guess is somewhere else?

Comment: What's the origin of the query? Can you be sure that the hebrew characters in the query are not mangled in some way? Btw it's good that the columns are encoded in utf8, but the character encoding used for the client connection independent.